# Pass custom data type from one database to another in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have created a custom data type (user defined table) in my database. I would like to pass this user defined table as a parameter to a stored procedure in a different database.

Is this possible.

thanks

Comment: Define precisely what you mean by "custom data type". If you used "create type", the short answer is no - because types are specific to databases. The longer answer is yes but you would need to convert it into a datatype that can be understood by both databases. Perhaps xml, json, some sort of delimited value in string, etc.

Comment: What about if I created this type (using create type) in both databases

Comment: @SMor cool idea with the JSON. I think I will try that

Comment: You can't pass a user created type to another database. The other database won't know what it is even if they are both defined the same. JSON or XML is the way to go there.